# How do I fire Facebook pixel within VueJS

Tags: javascript, facebook, vue.js, facebook-pixel

UPDATE WITH CORRECT CODE:

```
<script>
        export default {
            mounted() {
    //            this.comments_data = this.comments;
            },
            props: ['type'],
            data() {
                return {
    //                type: [],
                    email: '',
                    error_found: false,
                    email_error: '',
                    already_subscribed: '',
                    subscribed: false,
                }
            },
            methods: {
                subscribe(){
                    var vm = this;
                    vm.error_found = false;
                    vm.email_error = '';
                    vm.already_subscribed = '';
                    window.fbq('trackCustom', 'Custom Event Name Goes Here', {value: 1.00, currency: 'USD'});
                },
            },
        }
    </script>
```

I'm trying to fire a FB Pixel when someone clicks on subscribe button using VueJs. Code "vm.fbq.push('track', 'Even Name goes here', {value: 1.00, currency: 'USD'});" does not fire once someone clicks on the subscribe button. I have tried everything but with no luck. Does anyone know how to fire a Facebook pixel event from VueJS once someone clicks on a button?

```
<button @click="subscribe" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
    Submit
</button>
```

This is my VueJS Code

```
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
//            this.comments_data = this.comments;
        },
        props: ['type'],
        data() {
            return {
//                type: [],
                email: '',
                error_found: false,
                email_error: '',
                already_subscribed: '',
                subscribed: false,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            subscribe(){
                var vm = this;
                vm.error_found = false;
                vm.email_error = '';
                vm.already_subscribed = '';
                vm.fbq.push('track', 'Even Name goes here', {value: 1.00, currency: 'USD'});
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Bert, your suggestion does not work. It still does not fire.

Comment: You probably want `window.fbq`, not `vm.fbq`.

Comment: Side note: `var vm = this;` is totally unnecessary. Just use `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming you've loaded the FB pixel base code in [the normal manner](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/952192354843755?helpref=faq_content#addbasecode), you probably want `window.fbq`, not `vm.fbq`. `fbq` is not a part of your component.

Comment: ceejayoz: Yes, I loaded it in the normal manner. I changed the code to but the second alert does not come up
 alert('push initializing');
                        window.fbq('track', 'Bojan FBQ Push', {value: 1.00, currency: 'USD'});
                        alert('push fired');

Comment: @Boki_LV Do you get a JavaScript error in the browser console?

Comment: @ ceejayoz There is no error in the browser console but there is also no acknowledgement by Facebook that the event was fired. I placed those alerts so that I can see if the code executes. The first alert is shown but not the second one

Comment: Are you able to put a demonstration of the issue online somewhere? The second alert not being reached seems to very clearly indicate an error in the `window.fbq` line that's stopping the function from completing.

Comment: Got ti work. The application wasn't pulling in FB base code because it was in development mode and not in production. Thanks CeeJay. Your answer works like a charm